# How can I batch extract pdf?

Tags: wordpress, pdf, text

I have a list of PDF for recipes, which I want to embed in my recipe website. Is there any way to extract the entire text and formatting in bulk?  I will be working with 100s of pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a tool like this if you're trying to extract PDF to text.  I've used the image compressor version and it works very well.

[PDF to Text](https://pdftotext.com/)